# Hibernate custom validator, how to set propertyPath?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, orm

we've implemented a custom Validator.

We are getting the message back OK, but not the propertyPath, how can we pull that back?

implementation in our object

```
@RequiredIfSet.List({
        @RequiredIfSet(propertyPath = "reporterFirstName", field = "isFillingOutForSomeoneElse", dependentField = "reporterFirstName", message = "Reporter First may not be null"),
        @RequiredIfSet(propertyPath = "reporterLastName", field = "isFillingOutForSomeoneElse", dependentField = "reporterLastName", message = "Reporter Last may not be null"),
        @RequiredIfSet(propertyPath = "reporterContactPhone", field = "isFillingOutForSomeoneElse", dependentField = "reporterContactPhone", message = "Reporter Contact Phone may not be null"),
        @RequiredIfSet(propertyPath = "reporterEmail", field = "isFillingOutForSomeoneElse", dependentField = "reporterEmail", message = "Reporter Email may not be null")
})
```

//the constraint class

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = RequiredIfSetValidator.class)
public @interface RequiredIfSet {
    String field();
    String dependentField();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String message() default "Field Required";
    String propertyPath() default "";

    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        RequiredIfSet[] value();
    }
}
```

//where we loop through invalid fields

```
List<String[]> invalidFields = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Iterator<ConstraintViolation<T>> iterator = cv.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            ConstraintViolation<T> i = iterator.next();
            String property = i.getPropertyPath().toString();
            String message = i.getMessage();
            invalidFields.add(new String[] { property, message });
        }
        EntityValidationDTO EVDTO = new EntityValidationDTO();
        EVDTO.setStatus("fail");
        EVDTO.setInvalidFields(invalidFields);
        return EVDTO;
```

Answer (score 7):

In your "RequiredIfSetValidator", in method `isValid` add something like this:

```
if( !valid ) {
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).addNode("fieldName").addConstraintViolation();
}
```

Here is official documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#example-custom-error