# Hibernate custom constraint validator, how to set propertyPath explicitly?

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-validator

my custom class is implemented via:

```
@RequiredIfSet.List({
    @RequiredIfSet(field = "isFillingOutForSomeoneElse", dependentField = "reporterName", message = "may not be null"),
})
```

When I loop through my ConstraintViolations and whip it to the frontend via a DTO and ajax, I have getMessage() and getPropertyPath() in a little String[].

Works fine for everything, but propertyPath isn't set by this, as its not ON the field, its a list, how can i set it, or grab the field name to send back? Has been driving me crazy, have tried a few work around, also for note, heres where I loop:

```
public static <T> EntityValidationDTO GetEntityValidationDTO(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> cv){
        List<String[]> invalidFields = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Iterator<ConstraintViolation<T>> iterator = cv.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            ConstraintViolation<T> i = iterator.next();
            String message = i.getMessage();
            String property = i.getPropertyPath().toString();
            invalidFields.add(new String[] { property, message });
        }
        EntityValidationDTO EVDTO = new EntityValidationDTO();
        EVDTO.setStatus("fail");
        EVDTO.setInvalidFields(invalidFields);
        return EVDTO;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate custom valitor, how to set propertyPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645975/hibernate-custom-valitor-how-to-set-propertypath)